# parallel coordinates : setup color depending on value of dimension

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to change the stroke color according to the value of a dimension :
status 0 = red, status 1 = gree, status 3 = orange

I try to use the parallel coordinates library : https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/

There is a exemple there but it is to complicated, and I could not make it work, could someone tell me how to apply this on the simple example here ?

```
      pcz = d3.parcoords()("#example")
    .data(data)
    .hideAxis([])
    .composite("darken")
    .render()
    .alpha(0.35)
    .brushMode("1D-axes")  // enable brushing
    .interactive()  // command line mode
```

or maybe the one from the simple example there ?

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.parcoords.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d3.parcoords.css">
<div id="example" class="parcoords" style="width:360px;height:150px"></div>

<script>
var data = [
  [0,-0,0,0,0,3 ],
  [1,-1,1,2,1,6 ],
  [2,-2,4,4,0.5,2],
  [3,-3,9,6,0.33,4],
  [4,-4,16,8,0.25,9]
];

var pc = d3.parcoords()("#example")
  .data(data)
  .render()
  .createAxes();
</script>
    enter code here
```

Comment: Can you say a bit more about how this would look? Do you want to change the stroke color of each line as it goes through the different dimensions, based on the value? Do you have a mock-up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to the color parameter on initialization like:

```
var color = function(d) {
    if (d['displacement (cc)'] < 100) {
        return 'black';
    } else if (d['displacement (cc)'] > 400) {
        return 'red';
    } else {
        return 'yellow';
    }
};
var parcoords = d3.parcoords()("#example")
    .color(color)
    .alpha(0.4);
```